Next.js and express.js are not working properly when I deploy them
I am developing a project with next.js and express.js, I have finished the auth part, it works properly on localhosta, but when I deploy both in vercel, it throws a request when logging in, the data is saved in the cookie, but it does not redirect, the cookie is deleted when I refresh the page.
It doesn't work even though I set the cookie settings properly in Express.js
const express = require("express");
const https = require("http");
require("dotenv").config();
const dbConnect = require("./libs/dbConnect.js");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const userModel = require("../models/user");
const { hashData, compareData } = require("../helpers/bcrypt");
const CustomError = require("../helpers/customError");

dbConnect();

const app = express();
const server = https.createServer(app);

const corsOptions = {
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_HOST,
    credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.post("/auth/login", async (req,req) => {
    const { text, password } = req.body;
    const { MAX_AGE, NODE_ENV } = process.env;

    const user = await userModel.findOne({ $or: [{ username: text }, { email: text }] }).select("+password");
    const comparePassword = compareData(password, user?.password);

    if (!user || !comparePassword) {
        return next(new CustomError("kullanıcı adı ve ya şifreniz yanlış", 400));
    }

    
    const token = createToken({ user.userId });
    const maxAge = Number(MAX_AGE) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    res.cookie("token", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: NODE_ENV === "production" ? false : true,
        sameSite: NODE_ENV === "production" ? "lax" : "None",
        maxAge: maxAge,
    })
        .status(status || 200)
        .json({ message:"login true" });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`listening to port ${port}`);
});

frontend
"use client";
import AuthLayout from "@/components/authLayout";
import Button from "@/helpers/button";
import Input from "@/helpers/form/input";
  import axios from "axios";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { cn } from "tailwind-cn";

const LoginPage = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ text: "", password: "" });
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const isEmpty = Object.values(data).every((item) => item === "");

        if (isEmpty) return;

const url = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL;

        try {
            setLoading(true);
            const res = await axios.post(`${url}/auth/login`, data, { withCredentials: true });
            if (res.status === 200) {
                toast.success(res.data.message);
                router.push("/dashboard");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error(error.response.data.message ?? error.message);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    const styled = {
        login: `flex flex-col gap-4`,
        resetPassword: `text-hover text-sm capitalize ml-auto`,
    };

    return (
        <AuthLayout>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={cn(styled.login)}>
                <Input
                    name='text'
                    type='text'
                    SetValue={(e) => setData({ ...data, text: e.target.value })}
                    value={data.text}
                    isDisabled={loading}
                    labelText='e-posta ve ya kullanıcı adı'
                />
                <Input
                    name='password'
                    type='password'
                    SetValue={(e) => setData({ ...data, password: e.target.value })}
                    value={data.password}
                    isDisabled={loading}
                    labelText='şifre'
                />

                <Link href='/auth/reset-password' className={cn(styled.resetPassword)}>
                    şifreni mi unuttun?
                </Link>

                <Button isloading={loading} type='submit' className='mt-2.5'>
                    giriş yap
                </Button>

                <div className='capitalize text-sm flex gap-1'>
                    hesabın yok mu?
                    <Link href='/auth/register' className='text-hover'>
                        kayıt ol
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </form>
        </AuthLayout>
    );
};

export default LoginPage;



Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
